# Beta regression with random effects in R: different results in GAMLSS vs. glmmADMB

Tags: repeated-measures, random-effects-model, generalized-additive-model, beta-regression, gamlss

I am trying to fit a beta regression model to some repeated-measures data.
I fit the model both with the function `glmmadmb()` in the `glmmADMB` package, and the `gamlss()` function in the `gamlss` package but obtained very different significance results.
I'd appreciate any help to understand what's going on in the gamlss model (which I assume is the less reliable) and whether the difference in results is due to the model being somehow misspecified.

My dependent variable, `Y`, is a vector of proportions falling in the interval (0,1). The actual range is [0.0011, 0.0074], so very small proportions.
My independent variables are a two-level factor `cCondition` (`A` = .5 vs. `B` =-.5), and time (i.e., 14 time points) which I have turned into a second-order orthogonal polynomial `t1` (linear term) and `t2` (quadratic term).
Participants (`ID`) were measured at each time point, hence the repeated-measures nature of my data.

Here is a plot of the data:

[image]

(1) glmmADMB (NOTE: I get the warning: `In .local(x, sigma, ...) :'sigma' and 'rdig' arguments are present for compatibility only: ignored`)

```
m.admb <- glmmadmb(Y ~ (t1 + t2)*cCondition + (t1 + t2 |ID), data=mydata, 
                   admb.opts=admbControl(shess=FALSE,noinit=FALSE),
                   extra.args="-ams 500000000",
                   family='beta', verbose=T)

AIC: -4505.4 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -5.58188    0.03256 -171.42   <2e-16 ***
t1            -0.18131    0.12192   -1.49     0.14    
t2            -0.00172    0.12190   -0.01     0.99    
cCondition    -0.00263    0.06512   -0.04     0.97    
t1:cCondition  0.15018    0.24384    0.62     0.54    
t2:cCondition -0.10165    0.24380   -0.42     0.68    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Number of observations: total=448, ID=32 
Random effect variance(s):
Group=ID
             Variance    StdDev
(Intercept) 1.125e-07 0.0003354
t1          2.056e-05 0.0045342
t2          2.196e-05 0.0046864
```

(2) GAMLSS (NOTE: I get the `Warning message: In RS() : Algorithm RS has not yet converged`)

```
m.gamlss <- gamlss(Y ~ (t1 + t2)*cCondition + re(random=~t1+t2|ID), 
              sigma.formula = ~(t1 + t2)*cCondition,
              family=BE, data=mydata)

Mu link function:  logit
Mu Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -5.912492   0.006692 -883.477  < 2e-16 ***
t1            -0.229623   0.018740  -12.253  < 2e-16 ***
t2            -0.025312   0.021476   -1.179  0.23936    
cCondition    -0.010020   0.013385   -0.749  0.45460    
t1:cCondition  0.183171   0.037480    4.887 1.56e-06 ***
t2:cCondition -0.138822   0.042953   -3.232  0.00135 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Sigma link function:  logit
Sigma Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -4.95978    0.03370 -147.190  < 2e-16 ***
t1            -0.01726    0.12704   -0.136   0.8920    
t2            -0.92023    0.13596   -6.768 5.49e-11 ***
cCondition     0.07933    0.06739    1.177   0.2400    
t1:cCondition -0.02188    0.25408   -0.086   0.9314    
t2:cCondition  0.63396    0.27192    2.331   0.0203 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

-------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: Additive smoothing terms exist in the formulas: 
i) Std. Error for smoothers are for the linear effect only. 
ii) Std. Error for the linear terms maybe are not accurate. 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of observations in the fit:  448 
Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  97.56281
      Residual Deg. of Freedom:  350.4372 
                      at cycle:  20
```

A mixed linear model fit with the lmer() function in lme4 gives a significant main effect of t1.